# Why does moving the adverb to the front remove ambiguity?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

Take the sentence

> Students who study physics rigorously learn math.

As it stands, 'rigorously' can modify either 'study' or 'learn'. But if we move the adverb to the front to get

> Rigorously, students who study physics learn math.

'rigorously' unambiguously modifies 'learn' and not 'study.' This should be clear to any native speaker of English. However, when I think about it this phenomena, it's not clear at all why this must be the case. After all, might it not be more logical for the adverb to modify the closest verb? What are the (scientific) explanations of this sort of syntactic behavior?

Comment: In general, it doesn't. In some cases, it can. In this case, it's not clear that movement is improvement. How about "Students who study physics rigorously also learn math"? Adding a clarifying word, rather than making a  random syntactic move, is more likely to help clarify. There are several issues here; is it possible to learn math in any other than a rigorous way? Not really; math is all about rigor. But engineering math is much more concerned with results and formulae, and knowing how to read scales and curves accurately. BTW, don't expect grammar to be "logical".

Comment: @JohnLawler, naive set theory is non-rigorous math, as compared with axiomatic set theory.  The differential calculus with infinitesimals was, classically at least, non-rigorous, as compared with the development based on limits of series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex NP constraint, a grammatical principle discovered by John Ross, prohibits moving something from within a relative clause (RC) to a position outside the NP which contains the relative clause.  So, starting from

> [S [NP students [RC ... rigorously ] ] ... ]

to get to

> [S rigorously [NP students [RC ... __ ] ] ... ]

would require breaking this constraint.  However, starting from

> [S [NP students [RC ... ] ] rigorously ... ]

moving "rigorously" to the beginning of the sentence does not break the law.

Thus, assuming the sentence is structurally ambiguous depending on whether "rigorously" is interpreted as part of the RC modifying "students" or not, the version with the adverb at the beginning could only have come from a sentence structure with the adverb outside of the RC.

John Lawler has a nice account of the [Ross constraints](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html) on line -- see number 4 in his list.

Comment: God in Heaven!!

Comment: Looks like you got the answer you wanted.  God help you if you actually try writing that way. Erik Kowal is rude, but dead on as to the uselessness of putting "rigorously" first.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock God help you and Erik for completely missing the point of the question.

Comment: You asked why moving it to the front removes ambiguity. There is no possible answer to that question, because it is **based on a false premise.**  Why do pigs fly?

Comment: Why drag religion into this mess now?

Comment: Keep your eye on the ball, people.  The question was not about grammaticality, and neither is my answer.  The questioner was clear in describing the ambiguity he was concerned about, and my answer was qualified by the assumption that the ambiguity exists.  I said in a previous comment that I don't find the sentence with "rigorously" in initial position to be normal English, personally.  But this is just not relevant to either the question or my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the adverb immediately in front of the *verb* instead of the *sentence* eliminates the ambiguity, and also produces a structure that sounds like something a native speaker of English, and not a Martian, might generate **:

> "Students who **rigorously** study physics learn math".

Incidentally, the assertion that in the sentence

> "Rigorously, students who study physics learn math",

'rigorously' unambiguously modifies 'learn' and not 'study', is incorrect.

It doesn't modify either of those verbs (unambiguously or otherwise), because very few native speakers with normal cognitive abilities exist who would ever think of uttering (or writing) such a barbarism. Insofar as it can be said to modify anything at all, it modifies *the entire sentence.*

---

** Though the Martian would at least deserve some credit for effort.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot agree with this. It will be clear to any native speaker of English that in the second sentence, 'rigorously' modifies 'learn'.  Whether such an expression is ideal is entirely separate from the question at hand.  Grammatical =/= ideal.

Comment: I am also unenthusiastic about the acceptability of "Rigorously students learn math".  It sounds very strange.  However, if it's possible at all, it seems clear that the "rigorously" must modify the "learn math".  (I am a native speaker.)

Comment: Sorry, user118723, I'm with Erik here.  An adverb + comma at the beginning modifies the whole sentence (cf. normally, usually, unfailingly, unequivocally, etc.).  And "rigorously" modifying the whole sentence is without meaning.

Comment: "I'm sorry, but I cannot agree with this."  I'm tempted to make a really smart ass comment like "when you learn English, you'll agree with Erik"  :)

Comment: just fwiw (actually as STEVEN says, sorry missed it) I would interpret the  very strange form "Rigorously, blah blah blah" as meaning "Regarding the theorem, concept, or fragment blah, blah, blah, here's a statement of it in a rigorous manner" (or possibly, "and now we'll go on to look at it in a rigorous manner.") Exactly as  physicist might say "More rigorously, blah blah .." in continuation of a previous thought.

Comment: @user118723 - You cannot plausibly treat grammaticality as a quality that is unrelated to conformity with normal usage (or to meaning, for that matter). Not all adverbs are interchangeable from a grammatical perspective; nor are all transitive verbs, or intransitive verbs, or ..., or ... (Oh, and what Joe Blow said in his first comment. :)

Comment: I find this answer pretty irritating.  It doesn't say anything that is relevant to the question that was asked, and because of some disagreement with the questioner about acceptability of examples, it is gratuitously insulting.

Comment: @GregLee - It seems to me that you've misconstrued the nature of the OP's construction. It's not unacceptable as an *example*, it's unacceptable as an *actual query sentence*.  This is because it is severely malformed in terms of Standard English usage, and is therefore *incapable* of making the kind of sense (whether grammatical or syntactic) that the questioner is attempting to impose on it. As for the tone of my answer: you feel it's gratuitously insulting, I feel it's humorously lighthearted. We'll have to agree to differ on this point.

Comment: No, I don't have to agree with you at all, Erik.

Comment: Correction to a typo in my last comment: I meant *semantic*, not *syntactic*.

Comment: “It will be clear to any native speaker of English that in the second sentence, 'rigorously' modifies 'learn'.” ← No, it most certainly will not. As other comments have already shown, it is clear to many (I would venture pretty much _all_) native speakers that _rigorously_ in the second sentence does not in any way directly modify _learn_, but the entire sentence.

Comment: I agree with @Janus and Erik. There is a difference between *"Rigorously, this theorem needs to be proved using prolate spheroidal wave functions,"* and *"This theorem rigorously needs to be proved using prolate spheroidal wave functions,"* and that the second doesn't make any sense. (This is how *rigorously* is used as a sentence adverb.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If it modifies the entire sentence, it modifies 'learn' automatically because the [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of a sentence is a verb. In this case, the head is 'learn'.

Comment: @user118723 Note that I said _directly_. Modifying a sentence modifies everything in the sentence, not just its head; _rigorously_ modifies (to the extent that it really ‘modifies’ anything at all) _learn_, but it also modifies _study_, _math_, _students_, and _who_. But the only thing it _directly_ ‘modifies’ is the sentence itself.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You are incorrect. Adverbs that modify an entire sentence must necessarily modify its head only, as in the example "Instinctively, grizzly bears from Alaska hibernate."  Only 'hibernate' gets modified.

Comment: @user118723: adverbs can modify the entire sentence ***without*** modifying just the verb. Consider: "*Strangely, the preacher spoke about art"* and *"the preacher spoke strangely about art"*.

Comment: Presumptuous, perhaps, but the OP was not so impolite and arrogant to merit a stinging and frankly, quite rude, riposte.